# What is the dual of integration over the unit interval?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, dual-spaces

Let $C[0,1]$ be the collection of continuous functions on the unit closed interval $[0,1]$.
It is a vector space with respect to the usual addition and scaler multiplication.
Let $\Phi:C[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ be defined by

$$\Phi(f)=\int_0^1f(x)\,dx.$$

(whether Riemann or Lebesgue, not important)
Then, it is immediate that $\Phi$ is a linear functional.

Question) What is the dual of $\Phi$?
More precisely, what is the dual element $\phi\in C[0,1]$ corresponding to the linear functional $\Phi$?
Is it $f$?
Why?

By *dual element*, I mean the following

---

(1) If $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$, there corresponds the dual space $V^\ast$ of all linear functionals of $V$ into $F$.

(2) If V is a finite dimensional vector space with basis $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$, the correspondence between $V$ and $V^\ast$ can be easily described by the dual bases as
$$f_i(v_j)=\delta_{ij}$$
where $\{f_1,\cdots,f_n\}$ is the corresponding basis for $V^\ast$ and $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta.

(3) The correspondence in the finite dimensional case is actually an one-to-one correspondence (bijection).
So $f_i\in V^\ast$ is the dual element of $v_i\in V$ and $v_i\in V$ is the dual element of $f_i\in V^\ast$.

(4) I don't know if there is such a bijection if $V$ is infinite-dimensional and how to set the *basis* for such a function space.

Comment: In general for infinite-dimensional spaces, there is no isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$.  Note:  Even in finite-dimensional case, your dual element depends on the choice of basis.

Comment: @GEdgar My understanding to your Note : Consider $\mathbb R^3$. The standard basis $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$ has the corresponding dual basis $f_1$, $f_2$, $f_3$ defined by $f_i(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_i$ for each $i$. It has the property $f_i(e_j)=\delta_{ij}$ and we can assign the unique linear functional $f=a_1f_1+a_2f_2+a_3f_3\in\left(\mathbb R^3\right)^\ast$ to each vector $a_1e_1+a_2e_2+a_3e_3\in\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @GEdgar Instead, we can set basis for $\mathbb R^3$ as $2e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$. The corresponding dual basis should be $\frac12f_1$, $f_2$, $f_3$ since $(\frac12f_1)(2e_1)=1$. Then, while the first isomorphism maps $e_1\mapsto f_1$, the second isomorphism maps $e_1=\frac12(2e_1)\mapsto \frac12(\frac12f_1). So the two isomorphism is not identical ; the behavior of the isomorphism depends on the choice of the basis. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not quite what you wanted but in a very meaningful sense does answer the question of "what is the dual?".

For $C(X)$ where $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, such as $[0,1]$, we have a lovely description of the positive elements of $(C(X))^\ast$ up to isomorphism in the [Riesz-Markov-Kakutani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) representation theorem (actually this talks about LCH spaces and $C_c(X)$ but if $X$ is compact Hausdorff $C(X)=C_c(X)$ and it is also LCH). The theorem relates *positive* linear functionals on $C(X)$ with Radon measures on $X$.

Under this, the dual of integration is simply the Lebesgue-1 measure on $[0,1]$. If you like, the dual is the 'uniform distribution' on $[0,1]$.

Comment: I wish I would understand the whole things that you mentioned. I think I have encountered the whole terms in your answer in Analysis class, but I'm not really into it. So you're saying that the dual element of the linear functional is the Lebesgue measure or the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Thanks.

Comment: @govindah Yes. There are lots of theorems like this, most of them called the "Riesz" theorem. For instance we know the dual space of $L^p$ is, in many cases, isomorphic to $L^q$ so that it's sensible to say: "the dual of this functional $F$ is this funct*ion* $g$"

Comment: Yeah. I think I learned the stuff like that : the relation between $L^p$ and $L^q$. To understand the related things like Lebesgue mesure, $L^p$, Radon-Nykodym, locally compact Hasudorff and Riesz representation. (Among them, I fully understand the Lebesgue mesure and $L^p$ for some extent but not the remainder) I need to study a little bit. Can you recommend me a compact book? I've read Rudin's RCA, unsucessfully.

Comment: @govindah I quite liked [this](https://s2pnd-matematika.fkip.unpatti.ac.id/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Real-Analysis-4th-Ed-Royden.pdf)

Comment: @FSrike It seems to me that your saying about the duality of function space is included in 16.2, **The Riesz-Frechet Representation Theorem**. It may takes some time, but will be interesting. Thanks.